# Segmentation fault(core dumped) while installing python-openstackclient

Tags: python, python-3.x, openstack

I am trying to install python-openstackclient on Ubuntu 18.04

Facing below error:

````
Installing collected packages: typing-extensions, zipp, importlib-metadata, pbr, stevedore, pyparsing, packaging, wrapt, six, debtcollector, netifaces, importlib-resources, netaddr, pytz, iso8601, oslo.i18n, oslo.utils, simplejson, munch, jsonpointer, jsonpatch, requestsexceptions, jmespath, decorator, pycparser, cffi, cryptography, dogpile.cache, PyYAML, os-service-types, chardet, idna, certifi, urllib3, requests, keystoneauth1, appdirs, openstacksdk, PrettyTable, pyperclip, wcwidth, colorama, attrs, cmd2, cliff, osc-lib, msgpack, oslo.serialization, python-novaclient, python-cinderclient, rfc3986, oslo.config, python-keystoneclient, python-openstackclient
Segmentation fault (core dumped) ```


Python version: 3.6.9 
pip version: 9.0.1
````

Comment: You seem to use pip to install it. If so, I guess your version of pip is incompatible with your Python libraries. Have you tried apt instead?

Comment: Also, I suggest you search the internet for *pip segmentation fault*. Here is one possible solution; I am sure there are others: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55309683/3548109.

Answer (score 0):

try to install with  -vvv flag to be be more verbose , I guess cryptography packages core dumped, try to install  with:

```
pip3 install cryptography
```